# Avoiding user input errors

Tags: bash, shell

Hi everyone and thanks in advance.

I have a question for you. 
In a shell script that I made to manage the startup/shutdown of a Jboss application cluster I use a function to answer various question during the process which tells the script wath to do

```
function ThreeOptions
{
 ACT=0
 read -n 1 -s answ
 case ${answ:0:1} in
    n|N) echo "Operation skipped"
         ABRT=2
    ;;
    e|E|x|X) echo "Operation aborted"
         ABRT=3
         CloseProcedure
    ;;
    y|Y|*) echo "...ok..."
           ACT=1
    ;;
 esac
}
```

The function is written that way so that single pressure of the letter will select the option, and "Enter/Return" (well every other key indeed) will use the default.

How can I prevent the read command from reading unintentionally double/multiple keyboard inputs (aka sloppy hands).

EX.

```
echo -en "  Shall I close all Jboss processes ? [Y/n/e]: "
ThreeOptions
...
echo -en "  Shall I do some other thing?"
ThreeOptions
...
```

If I press "yy" I notice that I'm answering the ACTUAL question and the NEXT too.

PS: First question, so I hope it's understandable and that I didn't write too much :)

Comment: can't you just **flush** the input before you print the option? e.g. with `read -t 1 -n 10000 discard ` ?

Comment: Yep...that was exactly whay I was looking for!
Thanks a lot! 
Just added -s so that possible multiple outputs are not shown on screen

    read -t 1 -n 10000 -s discard

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` you can try the [shell pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) in the bash `case` structure.

For example use `+([y])|+([Y])|*)` instead of `y|Y|*)`

**Edit**: remember to call `shopt -s extglob` in the function before using the `case`.

Comment: Uhm...doesn't seem to work, do I have to escape something?
Only with `[y]|+[Y]|*) `  it seems to work without syntax errors but the main problem remains, pressing "yyy" will actually give 3 answers

Comment: Try to set `shopt -s extglob` in the function before using the case